# bootstrap-vue vuejs dynamic async component import

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue, tree-shaking

I would like to import a single bootstrap component dynamically only when I need it.

Bellow syntax actually can do it but it does import all components.

So final module bundle after tree-shaking is 1.4MB (entire bootstrap library).

```
 BNavbar: () => import('bootstrap-vue').then(module => module.BNavbar),
```

How can I change it to import only navbar to be equivalent of

```
import { BNavbarPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BNavbarPlugin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to wrap it in another component like `AppNavbar` which imports the `BNavbarPlugin` the basic way `import { BNavbarPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'` Then import your wrapper component dynamically

```
AppNavbar: () => import('@/components/AppNavbar')
```